# Using cucumber with jruby

Tags: cucumber, jruby, gherkin

I'm working on my company's intranet with

- cucumber 0.8.5
- gherkin 2.1.5

And I'm trying to switch from using ruby 1.8.7 to jruby 1.5.1

However, whenever I try to run cucumber from jruby, I get an error:

```
% jruby -S cucumber
/usr/local/src/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/site_rub/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require': no such file to load -- gherkin (LoadError)
```

I think this is b/c gherkin 2.1.5 is a native extension, and jruby can't handle it:

```
% jgem install gherkin-2.1.5.gem
...
ERROR: Error installing gherkin-2.1.5.gem:
       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Now, I'd love to just try updating versions, but since this is on a protected intranet, importing new software is a PITA, and takes some time.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can make the software I have work?  Am I missing a proper configuration setting or some such?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the JRuby version of gherkin. If you simply do

```
jgem install gherkin
```

you will get the correct version automatically. Otherwise, you have to figure out the URI to the JRuby version of the gherkin gem yourself and download it by hand.

But really, there is only one sensible thing you can do if you are working for a company that asks you to do a job and then ties your hands behind your back: run, as fast as you can, as far away as you can.

Comment: I up-voted your answer purely for your "run as fast as you can" advice.